# Neovim - Run a forward command with python

Tags: neovim

I need some help with writing a python plugin.

I know how to create a plugin but I can't find a way to run a forward or any normal mode stuff. I know I can run commands like echo with `self.vim.command('echo "Hello"')`. But how can I run a forward like `fc` to find the nearest `c` character in the line with python? Also, I would like to run a search with `/`, how can I do that?.

The only solution that comes to my mind is writing a vimscript function and call it in python with `exec function()`. But I would have to write one function for each thing I need. I would call it a workaround. I need a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [`:h python-command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html#following)?

Comment: @muru Love you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the “normal! fc” in as an ex command to run a normal mode command. The ! sign diasables mapping, so will use the command’s original difinition in vim.